# Установщик linux не видит внутренний жёсткий диск

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ssd, uefi

ноутбук acer aspire на uefi lnsydeh20 не видит жёсткий диск для установки системы, на этапе установки дистрибутива (linux mint 19.4 64, debian 10 64) видит для разметки только установочную флешку моего дистрибутива, загрузился с livecd, баш с команды sudo fdisk -l тоже видит только флешку, ssd до этого не размечал и не форматировал, отключил secure boot в efi, ноутбук новый, прошу помощи, заранее спасибо

Вывод `sudo fdisk -l`:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIYh6.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyYGt.jpg]

Answer (score 6):

Все, решил, надеюсь кто-то наткнется на этот вопрос при решении проблемы.
Нужно сменить настройку - изменить SATA mode в BIOS.

Программисты, извините, из Асера подгадили и здесь: эта опция по умолчанию в BIOS не отображается вовсе.

Нужно зайти в BIOS и в закладке Main нажать Ctrl-S. Только тогда появится возможность открыть этот раздел настроек - и после этого можете ставить на него, что угодно, системы диск увидят.

Comment: Помогло для ACER nitro 7. Спрятали такую важную настройку за ctrl+S, хотя именно этот ноут брал как OS Linux.

Comment: Помогло , ато два дня не мог понять почему не видно HD . То же Aspire.Спасибо за подсказку

Comment: странно, деб 10 нормально видит нвме

Comment: Почему это общий ответ? Правка не добавила полезной информации.

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо! Потратил целый день на форумах и помог ваш ответ. Для уточнение добавлю что из вариантов SATA mode: optane without RAID, optane with RAID и AHCI,  заработало с последним!