# Установщик линукс пытается установить его на флешку

Tags: linux, установка, kubuntu

Купил новый ноутбук без ОС. Решил первый раз в жизни поставить себе линукс. Выбор пал на Kubuntu. При установке, после выбора расслкадки клавиатуры вылезает следующая ошибка:

```
"На этом компьютере только 4 GB. Необходимо не менее 8.6 GB места на диске для установки Kubuntu"
```

4 GB это память загрузочной флешки. Я так понимаю проблема в том, что установщик пытается установить Kubuntu на флешку, а не жёсткий диск ноутбука. Помогите пожалуйста в решении и заранее прошу прощения, если это простая проблема, но поиск в интернете не помог.

UPD: в лайв режиме, в контроле устройств из жёстких дисков показывает только флешку

Comment: Обычно установщики предварительно спрашивают куда ставить, показывая доступные устройства. Если это не так, то может перед этим можно выбрать какой нибудь более продвинутый вариант установки, который спросит. Ну либо установщик не увидел жесткого диска в принципе, тогда возможно надо в bios выбрать другой режим дискового контроллера. Либо не повезло и ядро данного варианта linux в принципе не видит ваш диск

Comment: @Mike. Привет! При установке Kubuntu продвинутый вариант установки открывается примерно на 3 пункте установщика, у меня же установка прекращается на 2 пункте. Можете пожалуйста более подробно рассказать что именно нужно сделать в bios?

Comment: Ну если это проблема идентификация нужного драйвера диска, могу посоветовать попробовать [манжару](https://manjaro.org/downloads/official/kde/), может повезёт и загрузится. А то иногда бывает железо самому приходится прописывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была с SATA mode, который ACER скрыли из стандартного отображения BIOS. Если у вас возникнет такая же проблема, то мне помог вот этот вопрос

[Установщик linux не видит внутренний жёсткий диск](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105917/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-linux-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA)

Comment: это самый глупый вариант решения проблемы. отключить efi, перевести nvme в sata mode... лучше даже не придумаешь... а нужен вам линукс вообще? чем вы за компьютером занимаетесь?